# How to achieve concurrency in Dart stream controller

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, streamcontroller

Suppose I have an StreamController and I want to use this controller to add event to process multiple request at one (parallel) from app.

What I implemented was presented below:

In `main.dart`

```dart
    final controller = StreamController<Req>.broadcast();

    final resStream = controller.stream.asyncMap<Res>((request) {
      switch (request.method) {
        case "get":
          return  Future.delayed(
            const Duration(seconds: 10),
            () => const Res('response after 10s'),
          );
        case "post":
        default:
          return  Future.delayed(
            const Duration(seconds: 5),
            () => const Res('response after 5s'),
          );
      }
    });

    resStream.listen((event) {
      print('+++ response from stream: ${event.value}');
    });

    controller.add(const Req('get'));
    controller.add(const Req('post'));
```

Class `req.dart` & `res.dart`

```dart
class Req {
  const Req(this.method);

  final String method;
}

class Res {
  const Res(this.value);

  final String value;
}
```

After I ran that code. I realize the order of output is same with what order I added into StreamController before.

```
+++ response from stream: response after 10s
+++ response from stream: response after 5s
```

In my thinking the output of `Req('post')` must appear first then to another like this:

```
+++ response from stream: response after 5s
+++ response from stream: response after 10s
```

Anyone can help me to clear in this situation. Many thanks!

Comment: Stream.asyncMap I *believe* still enforces the order, so that the stream isn't scrambled.  If you want events to run in parallel, you'll need some sort of queueing that can ensure that no more than N at a time are started.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz : can you give me some evidences or examples to accomplish what you said. Thanks